# Why is my TimerTrigger'd function in my Azure WebJob app not being detected?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJob console app that won't recognize the `TimerTrigger` that I have set up.

I have the default `Program.cs` generated by Visual Studio:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
      config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }

    var host = new JobHost();

    host.RunAndBlock();
  }
}
```

I added my new function to `Functions.cs`:

```
public static void MyFunction([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *",
                                            RunOnStartup = true)]
                              TimerInfo timerInfo,
                              TextWriter log)
{
  log.WriteLine("MyFunction started!");
}
```

(I installed the `WebJobs.Extensions` NuGet package, so my code compiles fine.)

I also added this line:

```
config.UseTimers();
```

to the `Main` function as mentioned in [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/34032840/2747593), but for some reason, my new function still isn't triggered.

When I start the app, I see this output:

```
Found the following functions:
MyNamespace.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
Job host started
```

So it doesn't see my new function.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After comparing the contents of my `Program.cs` to what others had posted online (including [the TimerTrigger docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#local-development)), I found a small difference.

In the `Main` function, I changed:

```
var host = new JobHost();
```

to:

```
var host = new JobHost(config);
```

and it worked. I know for sure that I didn't change that before, so apparently this was a bug in the Azure WebJob template.

Comment: Also for anyone else facing this problem.. Timer triggers are found in the  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` nuget package